# Android Back Button closes the app in Capacitor 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I updated to Capacitor 3.0.1 with angular, but everytime I press hardware back button it closes the entire app...
I expect the older behavior, close push page, etc. what can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ionic Capacitor hardware back button is automatically closing the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67766576/ionic-capacitor-hardware-back-button-is-automatically-closing-the-app)

Answer (score 3):

Install @capacitor/app plugin

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app

I recommend reading the upgrade guide, it’s mentioned there
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/3-0

Comment: An important step from the guide: don't forget to clean your MainActivity.java. Capacitor 3 uses its own onCreate method that takes care of the back button.