# I plan to use the real device's back button. but every time I click the application closes. #ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

i'm having trouble manipulating the device buttons. I plan to use the real device's back button. but every time I click the application closes. i am using the capacitor in my project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67766576/ionic-capacitor-hardware-back-button-is-automatically-closing-the-app

I had this issue a while back, this is my question that I resolved and helped a few others resolve. Hope it helps you!

Comment: Show your code, how did you do that

Comment: import { MenuController, NavController, ActionSheetController, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';     constructor(
    public actionSheetController: ActionSheetController,
    private menu: MenuController,
    private router: Router,
    private platform: Platform,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    public _apiService: ApiService,
    public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private storage: Storage,) { 
      this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(10, () => {
        console.log('Handler was called!');
      });
     }

Comment: Capacitor Doctor

Latest Dependencies:

  @capacitor/cli: 3.1.2
  @capacitor/core: 3.1.2
  @capacitor/android: 3.1.2
  @capacitor/electron: 3.1.2
  @capacitor/ios: 3.1.2

Installed Dependencies:

  @capacitor/ios not installed
  @capacitor/cli 2.4.7
  @capacitor/android 3.0.0-rc.4
  @capacitor/core 2.4.7
  @capacitor/electron not installed

Comment: someone pleasee