# Uncaught (in promise) Error: "Device" plugin is not implemented on android

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am using the Device API from Capacitor (https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/device#deviceinfo) along with Ionic Framework and VueJS. The goal is to retrieve the UUID from an Android device.

When opening the application in my browser, I can see the device info that I'm logging. However, when opening it on an Android Device / Android Studio I get this error:

**Uncaught (in promise) Error: "Device" plugin is not implemented on android**

As far as I know the plugin is supported on Android.. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
import { Device } from "@capacitor/device";
async getDeviceInfo() {
  const info = await Device.getId();
  this.uuid = info.uuid;
  alert(this.uuid);
  const moreInfo = await Device.getInfo();
  const battery = await Device.getBatteryInfo();
  alert(JSON.stringify(moreInfo));
  alert(JSON.stringify(battery));
  alert("test");
},
```

Comment: `"import { Device } from "@capacitor/device";` this is work for capacitor 3.0 and this  `import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { Device } = Plugins;` capacitor 2.0

Comment: Odd: I did update to Capacitor 3, however the first line doesn't work. I tried the second one and indeed it works ;)..

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/67671607/1351469

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question

Answer (score 3):

the same error happened to me and I fixed it based on the documentation of the capacitor update for Android, removing the onCreate method from the MainActivity class.

```
 public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting to know that with Capacitor 3.x that they have moved the uuid into it's own function.

```
import { Device } from '@capacitor/device';

  async getdevinfo(){
    console.log('trying to get device info');
// works in browser
      const info = await Device.getId();
      console.log(info);
      console.log(info.uuid);

//wont work in browser
      const moreInfo = await Device.getInfo();
      const battery = await Device.getBatteryInfo();
      console.log(JSON.stringify(moreInfo));
      console.log(JSON.stringify(battery));

    console.log('post device info request');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

With Capacitor 4, you need to call `registerPlugin` *before* `super.onCreate`.

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  registerPlugin(MyPlugin.class);
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Instead of:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  registerPlugin(MyPlugin.class);
}
```

Comment: This was the correct solution for me. Should highlighted in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Did you run `npx cap sync` after installing @capacitor/device?
The command is always needed when you add new plugins.

Comment: The line const info = await Device.getInfo(); was not working for me. After npx cap sync it started working.