# I am trying to register capacitor v3 plugins to Android but nothing works

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am using Ionic 5, Capacitor 3, Android 4.2.2 Node 14...etc

I am trying to install capacitor plugins geolocation and storage in Android like so:

```
package io.ionic.seakah;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.capacitorjs.plugins.storage.StoragePlugin;>>>ERROR...cannot resolve symbol
import com.capacitorjs.plugins.geolocation.Geolocation;
import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    registerPlugin(StoragePlugin.class); >>>ERROR...cannot resolve symbol
    registerPlugin(Geolocation.class);>>>ERROR...registerPlugin not recognized

    // Initializes the Bridge
    // this.init(savedInstanceState, new ArrayList<Class<? extends Plugin>>() {{
       //Additional plugins you've installed go here
       //Ex: add(TotallyAwesomePlugin.class);

   // }});
  }
```

first thing of note is that the init method is deprecated and the add() is replaced with registerPlugin()...the problem is after all the adjustments the plugins aren't recognized...
I have made sure to run npm cap sync and also rebuild from inside Android studio. The existing documentation mostly speaks to Capacitor V2. would appreciate any help here...Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to register `Geolocation` or `Storage` plugins manually. Follow the [documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/geolocation). For `Geolocation` you should update `Manifest` for Android and it will work fine.

Plugins registration needed for custom plugins (probably for community plugins too): https://capacitorjs.com/docs/plugins/android

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing...the errors are from the manual registration.

Comment: @MichaelE You do not need to register these plugins manually. Why do you do this?

Comment: I was following the docs but may have made a wrong turn. I have managed to solve my problem with a whole lot of trial and errors. I can give your answer credit for leading me to the solution.

Comment: Same problem here trying to register community plug-ins but cannot resolve the symbols in MainActivity.java

What I can tell is that the package libs are not being loaded as the dependencies are not being added/injected into `../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins` when performing a sync. I just do not know enough yet about how plugin packages are detected and loaded into the android project structure.